# Make top of type sit on path - illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

Im trying to get type to sit on a path, so far ive been able to get it to work but when i try and get the type to sit the right way round (ie. not upside down) it sits on the inside of the path, which is on the wrong side of the circle (as the first image below).

I could align the circle by eye, but im sure there must be an easier way.

Is there a way to get the top of the type to site on the path as the sketch (second image below) ?

Ive also attached an .ai file if any one wants to play around with it. - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngvexixdckftkpt/type-on-path.ai

[image: type on path]
[image: top of type on path]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Select the Path with the type on it.
- Choose `Type > Type on a Path > Type on a Path Options`
- Check the **Flip** box
- Set the drop down for **Align to Path** to **Ascender**

[image: align to path]

Personally, if creating the circular badge style with type arching over the top and bottom, I prefer to set both type blocks to align to **Center** in the Type On a Path options. In this case, the only difference between the two type paths is checking the **Flip** box. It does create the need to possibly adjust the type paths to be a bit larger.

[image: center]

Answer (score 2):

At least as long as all your characters are roughly the same height, you can reduce their baseline with the advanced options of the character panel:

[image]

This way, the characters will sink below the path you specified. It won't align the tops of lowercase and uppercase, though -- you'll have to set the baseline shift of those characters by hand one by one to achieve the same effect.